# bootstrap-select not working with boostrap 4.1

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using bootstrap 4.1 and I want to make one select input searchable with boostrap-select js - https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select

For the tests i tried with

```
<select class="selectpicker">
<option>Mustard</option>
<option>Ketchup</option>
<option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

and initialize with `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();`
I add the library 1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js after the jquery and boostrap.js libraries

When I click on the select box, It is showing like this - 
[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Because bootstrap select Work with bootstrap 3

Comment: What can I use with boostrap 4 ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-select-v4

Comment: The plugin was updated for Bootstrap 4 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573624/bootstrap-4-styled-select

Answer (score 0):

Because bootstrap select Work with bootstrap 3. And there is so many major changes in between bootstrap 3 and 4. But you can download only bootstrap 3.* drop down CSS 
and js from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ and add to your project

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ht5qd1ch/)

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker">
<option>Mustard</option>
<option>Ketchup</option>
<option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

The bootstrap select, works with Bootstrap v. 3 See this link [support](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/#bootstrap-4-support)