# Two select boxes appear while there is only one in html

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[image: two boxes while the code says it is only one]

This is what I write:

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
<option>Test</option>   </select>
```

And the image is what I get.
Why it duplicates itself? How can I solve it? I use bootstrap and here is the complete code of the page:
This problem is the appearance of another select box which shoudn't happen. The code is composed of a single select box as you can see. But we see two select boxes. This is what the problem is.

https://pastebin.com/uTeVGvKP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bootstrap 4 styled select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573624/bootstrap-4-styled-select)

Comment: Can you at least create a working demo with minimum code that can reproduce the problem? Putting all your code here isn't helpful.

Comment: Allright, here is a link: 

https://www.animantoloji.com/beta/oku/one-punch-m/25/17 @DavidLiang

But first please click this link so that you can access the beta section which is also the link (this will grand you the permission of viewing the beta website): 
https://animantoloji.com/beta/betalog.php?sifre=animantobetalog

Comment: How did you generate those dropdown options (i.e., Sayfa 1, Sayfa 2, etc)? On server side with php or via ajax?

Comment: @AhmetEminKoçal: Are you trying to transform the native dropdown to some fancy looking mock dropdown using any jQuery plugin?

Comment: @DavidLiang its server side, from its database. Its php by the way. And you can use this link now: https://www.animantoloji.com/oku/one-punch-m/25/12

Comment: @DavidLiang Actually I do not do anything, just that code and it happens. It is probably related with the html theme I use

Comment: @AhmetEminKoçal: Idk. It's hard for me to figure it out. It seems to me that you might be using some jQuery plugin to transform a regular dropdown to fancier dropdown, and for some reason its style might be missing. That's why you're seeing 2 dropdowns.

Comment: @DavidLiang Idk too, It seems it will continue like that for some time more...

Comment: @DavidLiang I've found the solution. It was a css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a forgotten css file. I should have included bootstrap-select css file. And then add the select this `class="form-control show-tick"` and preferably take it into a div to limit its size.